# IDEA +tomcat, won't update the changes on javaFile when tomcat was restarted

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, intellij-idea, project-settings

My question is that recently I have started a web project in IDEA, with some servlet filter. At first it was ok ,but today I've found my **idea's hot deploy dosen't work** again.

For example,when I changed servlet , I need to hit ctrl+shift+F9 to recompile and it will work automaticlly. Now it just run like I didn't change it, even **restarted tomcat doesn't help**.

Now the only way to update changes is to **restart the IDEA** whenever I alter java file, servlet, filter, listener, java bean,etc.

I have checked the output path, **the class file did changed**, the  last modification date shows correctly,and I only had one output path.
I figure it is some thing to do with the project setting?

Here are some pictures of my project settings:
[image]

And also, whenever I creat a servlet or listener, it shows this **weird thing in the Web windows below the Project explorer**, like it was loading, sometimes it literally shows loading..., like this:
[image]

When I recompile the Module,it shows
**Warning: Output path D:\IDEADevelop\LittleBBS\web intersects with a source root. Only files that were created by build will be cleaned.**

Comment: I have figure out a solution.
---Settings >Build>Build Tools>Maven>Importing,I unselected the "Use Maven output directories"

Comment: If you're using maven (you didn't write it), it's better to let IntelliJ use the maven conventions

Comment: Thanks, i didn't ,haven't learn it yet...

Answer (score 0):

On the `Project` tab, replace
`D:\IDEADevelop\LittleBBS\web\WEB-INF\classes` with
`D:\IDEADevelop\LittleBBS\out`.

On the `Modules` tab, click the option `Inherit project compile output path`.

On the other tabs, ensure that the output directories are consistent to `D:\IDEADevelop\LittleBBS\out`

Comment: Thank you !!But my teacher tells me to change the class output to WEB-INF \ classes...I'll try to convincehim anyway...thanks